# CreateJS - Image bitmap doesn't alway show up

Tags: javascript, image, bitmap, easeljs, preloadjs

I suspect that the answer will lie in [PreloadJs](http://www.createjs.com/preloadjs), however, I've removed my tinkering around with it in my [code](https://jsfiddle.net/David952/ppbcndff/3/) to simplify it. Here is the most important part:

```
let stage = new createjs.Stage('easel'),
bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap('http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg');
stage.addChild(bitmap);
stage.update();
```

So now the problem, this is what you get when you run my code after the first time:

[image: original]

Nothing wrong.

However,  the first time you visit, the image isn't cached yet it, and *doesn't show up*. The same thing happens when you do hard reset the page(`ctrl + r` on windows). This is obviously a big deal because the first time you visit the page, it won't have images. Here is what I've tried:

- [PreloadJs,](http://www.createjs.com/preloadjs) this will most likely be the solution, but with my code so far it's not working.

  - This is my current `PreloadJS` code:

    ```
    queue.on('complete', draw, this)
    queue.load(imageUrl)

    function draw() {
      let bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(imageUrl);
      stage.addChild(bitmap);
      stage.update();
    }
    ```
- Triggering my code `onload`. The problem still occurs.
- Delays like `setTimeout`. Besides being extremely hackish, it only fixes it a percentage of the time, even with huge delays.
- Things like this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7029564/5461005). This will work for hard resets, but when I cleared my cache it took way too long to load, basically undermining the entire idea of fixing the first load.

So basically while some of these solutions while they work some of the time, some are hackish and all work only a percentage, or less of the time. What is the best solution?

One thing is that when I do something, such as resizing the page, the image would show up. I was not able to recreate this in my sample code. I believe this happened because when I initially ran `stage.update` it wasn't ready to show, so it didn't. Again simply running `stage.update` again a second later isn't good enough.

> **Note:** I do not believe this to be a duplicate of this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31681400/5461005) as there are no answers, it is a year old, they were unable to give some details, and the only solution offered in the comments failed.

Comment: If the link does work your first time please tell me, I have only been able to artificially create the conditions for a first time visit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your image is not loaded when you call `stage.update`. Even if you preload it, if you pass a string path to the Bitmap, it still takes time to initialize, but even if its just milliseconds, you have asked the stage to draw before it is ready.

The solution is to draw once the image is complete, and ensure you use the image, instead of a string path.

To fix your code:

```
let stage = new createjs.Stage('easel'),
bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap('http://www.skrenta.com/images/stackoverflow.jpg');
stage.addChild(bitmap);
bitmap.image.onload = function() {
    stage.update();
}
```

To fix your preload code:

```
queue.on('complete', draw, this)
queue.load(imageUrl)

function draw() {
  let bitmap = new createjs.Bitmap(queue.getResult("imgId")); // Reference
  stage.addChild(bitmap);
  stage.update();
}
```

Here is a more complete answer: [easeljs not showing bitmap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20850634/easeljs-not-showing-bitmap/20860996#20860996)

Comment: Ahh that's what I was forgetting `getResult` thanks. I've marked this a duplicate as well.